# Problems opening an alertDialog with a recyclerview

Tags: android

Error: `RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout`

I have seen several items that really look like this error here, but none have solved my problem. The list is loaded normally, only after adding the interface, which I created, by clicking on an item in the list (this click interface is used in other situations, usually), is that the error occurs. And recyclerview is created in alertDialog.
I tried changing the position of the code, since I saw that the list might not be filled when the adapter is loaded.

After going to the server, I return a list with items and only after this return, I create the items related to recyclerview and adapter. Working with asyncTask, it returns to activity through a method that is overwritten.

follow the codes

**Activity/dialog:**

```
public void buildDialogToPredicted(String whichDialog) {
    //method is created, after the return of the asynctask for the creation of the dialog with the list of predicted items

    startVoiceWave(this, this);
    View viewAlertDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.predict_layout, null);
    recyclerView = viewAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler_predict);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setView(viewAlertDialog)
            .setCancelable(true);
    final AlertDialog dialog1 = dialog.create();
    Button close = viewAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_predic);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);

            dialog1.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog1.show();
    dialog1.getWindow().setLayout(1050, 1400);
    switch (whichDialog) {
        case "predicaoCid.sucesso":
            final List<CidVo> list = MyApplicationInstance.getInstanceApplication().getCidVo();
            recyclerViewAdapterPredictCid = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapterPredictCid(list, this, new CustomItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                    list.remove(position);
                    recyclerViewAdapterPredictProd.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterPredictCid);
            break;

        case "predicaoProc.sucesso":
            final List<PredicaoProcedimentoVo> listProc = MyApplicationInstance.getInstanceApplication().getProcedimentoVosList();
            recyclerViewAdapterPredictProd = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapterPredictProd(listProc, this, new CustomItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                    listProc.remove(position);
                    recyclerViewAdapterPredictProd.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterPredictProd);
            break;

    }


}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdapterPredictProd extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerViewAdapterPredictProd.ViewHolder> implements CustomItemClickListener {

    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    private List<PredicaoProcedimentoVo> mDataset;
    // Animation
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;
    private ItemAgendaVo itemAgendaVo;
    private CustomItemClickListener listener;
    private View v;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public CustomRecyclerViewAdapterPredictProd(List<PredicaoProcedimentoVo> myDataset, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, CustomItemClickListener listener) {

        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_predict, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        PredicaoProcedimentoVo predicaoCidVo = getProcVo(position);

        setAnimation(holder.txtCID, position);

        holder.txtCID.setText(predicaoCidVo.getTextPredictedProc());
        listener.onItemClick(v,position);//erro ocorre nesta linha TODO

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if (mDataset != null) {

            return mDataset.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public PredicaoProcedimentoVo getProcVo(int position) {

        return mDataset.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's
        // animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    appCompatActivity, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            // Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            // appCompatActivity, R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
            // Animation animation =
            // AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(appCompatActivity,
            // R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
            // animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);

            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtCID;
        TextView txtCIDDesc;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            txtCID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCard1_item1);
            txtCIDDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCard1_item2);

        }
    }
}
```

Error occurs in the adapter, when it passes through `listener.onItemClick(v,position)` Thanks for the help.

Click class:

```
public interface CustomItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Comment: Put your logcat here.

Comment: Maybe you wanna set you listener to view instead of call when bind?

Comment: @Warrocker I'm sorry, but I not understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this it works for me inside Recyclerview :

```
  @Override
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    context = parent.getContext();
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_smiley, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: the difference, in the adapter, is `null` instead of `(.., parent, false)`?

Comment: Does your switch() case matches any of the 2 conditions you provided? Most probably that is causing the RecyclerView to not have an adapter.

Comment: @PankajSati yes, does match.

Comment: Debugging, I see that the error occurs while passing the line I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please post the logcat and code for CustomItemClickListener class as well

Comment: @PankajSati I understood the error, but I do not know how to solve it, yet. It's in the `list.remove` or `notifyDataSetChanged` .. I do not understand the reason, but, I put a `Toast` and it goes up the text before some click happens, I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was basic and I did not realize it. I did not implement a click on an item on the screen, like a textview, I just did it through the listener, directly.

Solved:

```
holder.txtCIDDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(v, position);
    }
});
```